# Visual Studio Code intellisense doesn't show parameters for decorated function

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, intellisense, python-decorators

For example, I have a simple function:

```
def foo(a):
    '''
    Some function.
    a : int
    '''
    print(a+10)
```

It works as I expected - when I mouse over the function I can see useful help:[image]

But if I wrap it in a decorator, this useful info about function parameters is lost:

```
def simple_decorator(f):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        '''
        Simple decorator
        '''
        res = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print('Wrapped')
        return res
    return inner

@simple_decorator
def foo(a):
    '''
    Some function.
    a : int
    '''
    print(a+10)
```

[image]
[image]

**BUT! I can see the info using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + mousing over the function:**

[image]

This way still can't help on showing parameters of function - when I add parenthesis I see only `*args, **kwargs` again.
I also tried `from functools import wraps` but it doesn't work too.

**Is it possible to make intellisense work correctly to show the parameters of a decorated function? Or maybe always show both of them, similar to what's displayed on <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + mouse over?**

I found a lot of closed issues on GitHub but still can't figure out hoqw to solve it. For example: https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/906

Comment: I can't reproduce with VSC 1.37 and the latest ms-python extension. Nor with Python 2.7 or Python 3.6. I get the same hints with and without decorator.

Comment: @rioV8 I use VS Code 1.37.0 and Python Extension 2019.8.30787. And tried everything. I tried disable Jedi too. Still the same problem. Can you show your code please?

Comment: They must have made a very recent update because I use ms-python 2019.8.29288

Comment: @rioV8 I tried 29288 but still have the same error. Can you show your code, please? Do you use `@wraps`?

Comment: I just Copy/Paste your source with the decorator

Comment: @rioV8 and you got docstring for `foo` or for `decorator`? Because I always have decorator description instead of foo!

Comment: Like I said in the first comment: **I get the same hints/docstring with and without decorator.**

Comment: @rioV8 Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197937/discussion-between-mikhail-sam-and-riov8).

Comment: The problem is not reproducible on VS Code 1.73.0, MIcrosoft Python v2022.18.2.

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me with Microsoft language server 0.3.59.0 (beta):
[image]

Comment: thank you for you reply. Can you please clarify a bit: what is a Microsoft Language server and how can I use it to fix my VSCode (if it's possible :) )

Answer (score 0):

Try `ctrl + space`
Or `^ + space`

I may solve the problem